# Wordpress (woocommerce): redirection + stripos issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to do a redirection from a single product page to another one if a word is found a string (which results from a CURL).

```
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_2', 20 );
function redirect_2() {
if (is_product('18456') && stripos($result, 'YES')!== false) {
wp_redirect('http://mywebsite/home/');
die();
}
}

?>
```

My wordpress (+woocommerce) website breaks down with this code. 
I don't understand since I already use a redirection which works perfectly fine:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_home', 10 );
function redirect_home() {
if ( is_product('18456') && !is_user_logged_in() ) {
wp_redirect( 'http://mywebsite/home/');
die();
}
}
```

Moreover I tested the stripos alone (with an echo) and it works well.

Comment: The variable `$result` is not defined in your first function…

Comment: Additionally, to troubleshoot, you must learn to be specific.  "Breaks down" is useless.  What specifically happens? Is there an error? IF so, what? If not, what happens that should / should not?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)